# How to clone a class that uses super()?

Tags: python, class, clone, super

The following Python program:

```py
def clone(cls):
    return type(cls)("Clone" + cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(vars(cls)))

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

CloneA = clone(A)
CloneA()
```

raises the following error (CPython 3.8.4 interpreter):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

How can I clone (not subclass) `A` and avoid this error?

Comment: Didn't you previously ask an identical question?

Comment: Since `A.__init__()` does nothing, you don't need to worry about it — in fact you could leave the `def` for it out altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `__class__ = cls` attribute:

```py
def clone(cls):
    namespace = dict(vars(cls), __class__=cls)
    return type(cls)("Clone" + cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, namespace)
```

`CloneA()` calls `CloneA.__call__(CloneA)` resolved to `type.__call__(CloneA)`, which calls `CloneA.__new__(CloneA)` resolved to `type.__new__(CloneA)` to create an instance `self` of `CloneA`, followed by `CloneA.__init__(self)`, which calls `A.__init__(self)`. Finally the latter calls `super()` (short for `super(__class__, self)`) which checks that `self` is an instance or subclass of `__class__` that is of `A`, that is that `self.__class__` or `type(self)` is a subclass of `A`. `type(self)` always returns `CloneA` while `self.__class__` can differ, as Guido mentioned in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#the-abc-module-an-abc-support-framework):

> Also, `isinstance(x, B)` is equivalent to `issubclass(x.__class__, B) or issubclass(type(x), B)`. (It is possible `type(x)` and `x.__class__` are not the same object, e.g. when `x` is a proxy object.)

Comment: [This fails if you try to clone a subclass of a cloned class.](https://ideone.com/cOjJUZ)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the code snippet, I had also noticed this issue. It is because `self.__class__` resolves to the subclass (`C` in your code) of the cloned class (`clone(B)` in your code), but it is not a subclass of the original class (`B` in your code). In other words, `issubclass(C, B)` is `False`. A more robust solution is to create a proxy of `self` with `__class__=klass` for each method of the cloned class. That way `self.__class__` is never shadowed by a subclass `__class__` attribute.